# Who has priority in this UK road junction?

Tags: uk, driving

Can you please let me know who has priority at this junction

1. My car is at the green highlighted area and want to turn right. Say there are cars already to turn right at the yellow highlighted area. what should I do? There is a give way sign for the yellow highlighted area vehicles.

should i wait for all the  yellow highlighted area vehicles to turn right and then proceed?or as there is a give way sign for them, can i proceed? Note that there is a pedestrian cross signal at the red highlighted area.

[image: juction picture link]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have priority turning onto the side road over the vehicles waiting to turn onto your road from that side road.

The side road has a double broken line threshold for the lane joining the main road, and a give way symbol on the road before that line, both of those indicate “give way to traffic on the road you are joining”.

The pedestrian crossing has no bearing on this.

Comment: To add, if the pedestrian crossing is showing red (and/or traffic is waiting there), the polite thing to do would be for the green driver to let the yellow driver out first, even though they don't have to.

Comment: The pedestrian _in_ the crossing, however, does have bearing on the situation. ;)

Comment: @AakashM I wouldn't have said so at all. If there is a pedestrian at the crossing it would make it so there is even less urgency for the yellow cars, as they will have to wait for the pedestrian anyway. Unless you are in stop start traffic, always just follow right of way. Otherwise confusion and misunderstanding will come into play and that's how accidents happen.

Comment: Screenshot from the point of view of the traffic that is supposed to yield here in case the community thinks it would be helpful to edit it in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCnry.jpg

Comment: Rule 170 in the highway code states "give way to pedestrians crossing or waiting to cross a road into which or from which you are turning. If they have started to
cross they have priority, so give way" Edit: I see now the original comment was about the pedestrian-crossing ahead, not the pedestrian waiting to cross in the side road but my comment still stands.

Comment: If the side road at the junction was narrow, or if you are driving something with a  large turning circle, you might choose to give way to the car in the yellow circle. Once he's out of the side road, turning into it gets easier. (Side road junctions down my way tend to come in two versions: just wide enough for two cars to pass each other, and just not wide enough for two cars to pass each other).

Answer (score -3):

In the UK we drive on the left, so the yellow circle indicates traffic coming towards us, which has no practical effect on our right-turn - unless some of the traffic emerging from the side road wants to turn right, in front of us. That is a common cause of accidents because it calls for common sense and politeness!

Comment: "unless some of the traffic emerging from the side road wants to turn right, in front of us" – Yes, that is the situation described in the question. Can you edit your answer to address that?